# Split C file by its functions

Tags: c, file, split

How can I automatically split a single C file with various functions in it into various files with only a single function each? Anyone have a script or let's say a plugin on notepad++ that could do it? Thank you

Comment: as much as it's completely off-topic as a question, you could try asking about it in chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: It might be impossible, and is certainly a ***very bad idea***. Please **edit your question** to explain why you need to do this. In some cases, you might want to split a rather long C file (more than several thousand lines) into a few smaller ones. This requires some work (which might not be automatable) and may introduce performance losses

Answer (score 2):

It may not even be possible. If a single global `static` variable exists in one of the files, it shall be shared by all the functions of that file but not be accessible (even with the `extern` modifier) from functions of other files. And even without that, processing of includes and global variables will be a nightmare.

Anyway, on Unix-Linux, the good old `ctags` command should be close to your requirements: it does not split the files, but creates an index file (called a tags file) which contains the file and position of all functions from the specified C, Pacal, Fortran, yacc, lex, and Lisp sources. The man page says:

> Using the tags file, ex [or vi, vim, etc.] can quickly locate these object definitions.
>        Depending upon the options provided to ctags, objects will consist of
>        subroutines, typedefs, defines, structs, enums and unions.

You can either use it (if on Unix world) or mimic it, on Windows for example.

Answer (score 1):

For reasons explained in [Serge Ballesta's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48587614/841108), splitting a single C file into smaller pieces is not automatable in general.

And having several small files instead of a larger one is generally a bad idea. The code becomes less readable, its execution could be slower (because there are less inlining and optimizing opportunities for the compiler).

In *some* cases, you might want to split a big C file (e.g. more than ten thousands lines of source code) into a few smaller ones (e.g. at least a thousands lines of code each). This may require some work, like renaming `static` functions or variables into a longer (and globally unique) name declared as `extern`, moving some *short* functions (or adding some macros) into header files and declaring them as `static inline`, etc. This cannot be really automatized in the general case.

My recommendation is often to *merge* a few small (but related) files into one single bigger one. As a rule of thumb, I would suggest having files of more than a thousand lines each, but [YMMV](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/your_mileage_may_vary).

In particular, there is no reason to have only one function definition in each of your source file. This practically forbids inlining (unless you compile with link-time-optimization, a very expensive approach).

Look into *existing* free software projects (e.g. on [github](http://github.com/)) for inspiration. Or look into the Linux [kernel](http://kernel.org/) source code.

**Splitting a C file into smaller ones** (or conversely, merging several source files in a single bigger one) **generally requires some [code refactoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring).** In many cases, it is quite simple (perhaps even as trivial as copy & pasting some functions one by one); in some cases, it could be difficult. You should do it manually and incrementally (and enable all warnings in your compiler, to help you find mistakes in your refactoring; don't forget to recompile often!). You may want to improve your naming conventions in your code while you split it.

Of course you need a [version control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) system (I recommend [`git`](http://git-scm.com/)), and you'll compile and commit your code several times while splitting it. You need also a good [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor) (I recommend [GNU `emacs`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), but it is a matter of taste; some people prefer [`vim`](http://vim.org/), etc ....).

You certainly don't want to automatize C file splitting (you might write some scripts to help you, generally it is not worth the trouble). You need to control that split.

Comment: Can you please put the full form of YMMV in bracket? Good answer.

Comment: Added an hyperlink explaining YMMV. BTW I am not a native English speaker, and I thought that YMMV is a common Americanism.