# Any good reasons not to split a file up into multiple files in rust

Tags: rust

I'm working on a large rust project. It's split into multiple workspaces, but occasionally I come across enormous files containing multiple modules. I wonder if there are any good reasons not to split (at least) each module into a separate file, other than readability?

Comment: The [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48588291/1707353) relative to the C programming language might also be true for Rust. The C compilers I know about don't take multiple compiler outputs (.o files) for further optimization.

Answer (score 1):

[Crates are compilation units](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/crates.html) so there's no downside wrt. optimization opportunities when you split up large files into smaller files / modules.

You could write your complete crate in a single `lib.rs` or `main.rs` but that makes working with the code a pain. With visibility rules, you can control the internal API surface of your crate through modules and enforce going through certain APIs instead of accessing internals of structures / private functions.

Splitting up your code into submodules can make your life easier when dealing with conditional compilation through feature gates if you encapsulate all code relevant to a given feature in a module of its own. That way you don't have to add a feature gate to every line / function pertaining to that feature but just put the attribute on the module declaration.